# Getter for a vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, getter

I have to make a getter for a vector for which i allocated the memory dynamically. My vector
contains bool values.

The program is working, but the way I implemented my getter it retuns me the adress of the vector. I tried to modify it but I couldn t get all the elements of my vector.Can someone help me please?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class myclass
{
bool* vector;
int NumberOfElements;
public:
void setNumberOfElements(int NumberOfElements)
    {
        if (NumberOfElements >= 0)
            this->NumberOfElements = NumberOfElements;
    }
int getNumberOfElements()
    {
        return NumberOfElements;
    }

void setVector(bool* vector,int NumberOfElements)
    {
        setNumberOfElements(NumberOfElements);
        this->vector = new bool[NumberOfElements];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfElements; i++)
            this->vector[i] = vector[i];
    }

bool* getVector()
    {
        return vector;
    }

};


int main()
{
    myclass c;
    c.setNumberOfElements(4);
    c.setVector(new bool[] {0, 1, 1, 0}, 4);
    cout << c.getNumberOfElements() << "  " << c.getVector() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with your getter? Usually for a dynamic array you'd have accessors for getting elements at specific indices. And functions to get iterators to be able to iterate over all elements in a loop

Comment: What you are calling "vector" is actually an _array_.  You allocated it with the _array new_ operator.  This is confusing because I think most people think "vector" refers to [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Also you need to read about [the Rule of Three (and friends)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) if you haven't already. If you do not correctly manage that allocation you're gonna be in a world of hurt later. At the moment you'll get away with the more vicious problems  because the allocation is leaked.

Comment: I want to obtain the elements from my vector. It s just a homework, I try to learn the basics. It s my first time working with a vector in this way, sorry if I didn t give you enough information. @UnholySheep

Comment: @GabrielBoşcan *It s just a homework, I try to learn the basics.* -- The "basics" shouldn't include writing classes that have memory leaks.  If you want to get into the dynamic memory handling business, it isn't a half-in, half-out situation.  You need to do everything correctly, including memory cleanup.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie My code was a bit longer, but  I tried to select only the thing that creates me problems. And also i thought it woul be confusing to see the names of my variables because I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: You cannot write a function that returns "all the elements" - you can return iterators or other wrapping classes (such as `std::span`), but even those won't work with your `std::cout` statement the way you want them to. If your aim is only to print all elements then you should probably overload `operator<<(ostream& os, const myclass& c)` or something along those lines

Comment: Understood. When you return a pointer, you return only the pointer, and the pointer doesn't know how many items are in the object it points at. If you print a pointer, you print the address of the object. If you want to print the number of items in the pointed-at object, you need to make a loop and supply the number of items, `c.getNumberOfElements()` in this case, to the loop.

Comment: @user4581301 So, from what I can understand i can t use a getter in this way to print the elemets of my array. I must use a loop, but where should i put it, inside the getter or in main when I use cout? I'm sorry for all the questions, but this is really confusing!

Comment: The getter isn't a good way to do this. See UnholySheep's comments about a `<<` overload. That's where all of the looping and to-text formatting should be. Once you've written a << operator, the user can simply `cout << c << endl;` In general you want the user to know as little about how the insides of an object work as possible. Expose too many details and users will use those details, reducing the ease of making changes in the future. For example, what if later you decide to save space and pack the booleans as bits? The user's `for` loop iterating what used to be `bool`s won't work anymore.

Comment: The getter is only useful when you want unformatted data, for example when you're going to dump the whole array into a function that needs an array or if you're writing to a binary file. And in the file dump case, you're better off adding binary read and write functions to the class that the user can call without having to know any details.

Comment: Keyword: Encapsulation. It's more than just making stuff `public` or `private`. If you have a `private` variable with a `public` getter that allows the user to change the data, what was the point of making the variable `private`? Do as much manipulation of an object's data inside the object as possible. That way you maintain control of the object's data. This defends the object from idiots and accidents and makes debugging a lot easier: You just have to monitor a few possible entry points.